# Include Filters for Entity Framework Core

Tags: linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I've been trying to find out information about filtering my calls to the database to reorder the data from the database and have found out their is no way yet to filter the `.Inclunde` or `.ThenInclude`.

Below is what I have tried, is there a way of sorting a collection?

```
var workout = await context.Workouts
                           //.Include(w => w.Segments.OrderByDescending(x => x.Id))
                           .Include(w => w.Segments)
                           .ThenInclude(s => s.Sets)     //this gets the sets for the segment
                           .Include(w => w.Segments)
                           .ThenInclude(s => s.Exercise)     //try intellisense didn't show exercise
                           .Include(w => w.BodyParts)       //to delete from bodyparts column need to fix
                           .SingleOrDefaultAsync(w => w.Id == id);


   .Include(w => w.Segments.OrderByDescending(x => x.Name))  //doesn't work

   .ThenInclude(s => s.Sets.OrderByDescending(x => x.Name))  //doesn't work
```

Below code can't convert order `IEnumerable` to my domain

```
var workoutSegments = workout.Segments.OrderByDescending(x => x.Name);

foreach( var segment in workout.Segments)
{
    segment.Sets.OrderByDescending(x => x.Name).ToList();
}    

return workoutSegments;

public class Workout
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Segment> Segments { get; set; }

    public Workout()
    {
        Segments = new Collection<Segment>();
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is 3rd party library to do orderby in include. I cannot remember what name. But I have another way.

```
var workout = await context.Workouts
     .Include(w => w.Segments)
        .ThenInclude(s => s.Sets)
    .Include(w => w.Segments)
        .ThenInclude(s => s.Exercise)
        .Include(w => w.BodyParts)
    .SingleOrDefaultAsync(w => w.Id == id);

workout.Segments = workout.Segments.OrderByDescending(x => x.Name);
foreach (var seg in workout.Segments)
{
    seg.Sets = seg.Sets.OrderByDescending(x => x.Name);
}
//Do same way for other includes.
```